# Interface for string field in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function `whichYogaDoYouPractice` that accepts a parameter `type`. The value of `type` can be any one of `hatha`, `kriya`, `bhakti`, `jnana`. Currently, I have my function written as follows:

```
function whichYogaDoYouPractice(type:'hatha'|'kriya'|'bhakti'|'jnana'){
 ...
}
```

I have more such functions where I want to use the parameter `type` for the above-mentioned values. I don't wish to mention all 4 `type`'s every time I declare a function. I want to create an interface so my function looks something like the below function:

```
function whichYogaDoYouPractice(type:YogaType){
 ...
}
```

I can create interface for objects like below:

```
export interface ObjectInterface{
 id:string;
 name:string;
}
```

But I want to create an interface only for a string that can only be of any of the 4 values I mention in the interface so that I can use it with one word `YogaType` for the above example. Is it possible in Typescript? If yes, how?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a union type:

```
type YogaType = 'hatha'|'kriya'|'bhakti'|'jnana'

function whichYogaDoYouPractice(type: YogaType){
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=49&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAmg9gcwIYBVzQLxQOQAsnD7YA+2A1gE4CWISJ2ARvmcFfQFYB2S32AUHwBmAV04BjVnE5QA7ripjc8ZABE48YQAUKSCQogAKUJABcsRKnQBKAN58AvkA)

Or create a enum:

```
enum Yoga {
  hatha,
  kriya,
  bhakti,
  jnana
}

function whichYogaDoYouPractice2(type: Yoga){
}
```